# PostGIS is rejecting an srid code for my projection. I've found a nearly identical projection w/ a legit srid. Will it work?

Tags: postgis, proj, srid, state-plane, nad83

My projection is this: `NAD 1983 StatePlane North Carolina FIPS 3200 Feet`, which has a proj4 string that looks like this:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=34.33333333333334 +lat_2=36.16666666666666 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2199999999 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs
```

Its SRID is 102719. I've tried to create a db column in PostGIS with an srid option for this projection, but its rejecting the srid, calling it invalid.

I've found a similar projection with a valid srid code, `NAD83 / North Carolina (ftUS)` (srid=2264), which has a proj4 string nearly identical to the above:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.16666666666666 +lat_2=34.33333333333334 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2192024384 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs
```

As you can see, the only difference between these two is that the `lat_1` and `lat_2` degrees are swapped. They even use the same three degrees, only the first two are differently ordered.

Can I use this second projection?

UPDATE: The answer seems to be leaning towards 'yes', I just ran projection-to-projection transformations from a single projection to the NC projection using the "legitimate" and "illegitimate" proj4's and got similar results down to the 7th decimal place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an ESRI projection ([ESRI:102719](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102719/)) however PostGIS (and everyone else but ESRI) are expecting [EPSG:2264](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2264/) (or possibly [EPSG:3359](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3359/) or [EPSG:3632](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3632/)). You can use the ESRI one (just be aware that this will not interoperate well with others) - just run the following:

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 9102719, 'esri', 102719, '+proj=lcc +lat_1=34.33333333333334 +lat_2=36.16666666666666 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2199999999 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2000000.002616666],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-79],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",34.33333333333334],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",36.16666666666666],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",33.75],UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924],AUTHORITY["EPSG","102719"]]');
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to do this: `ERROR:  new row for relation "spatial_ref_sys" violates check constraint "spatial_ref_sys_srid_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9102719, esri, 102719, PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet",GEOGC..., +proj=lcc +lat_1=34.33333333333334 +lat_2=36.16666666666666 +lat...).`

Comment: Its looking like there is an srid constraint limiting the srid number to `< 998999`, the one from spatialreference.org is well over that limit -- http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2012-July/034723.html

Comment: I've changed the `srid` from `9102719` to `102719`, which makes sense because that's what spatialreference.org says the srid is, even though their insert statement mentions the number w/ the 9 in front of it. I think this problem is solved but I'll post if there's any issue

Comment: I'm still getting an invalid SRID code error even after updating spatial_ref_sys.... `PG::RaiseException: ERROR:  AddGeometryColumn() - invalid SRID`

Comment: I'm creating a temporary column with SRID 2264 for the time being...

Comment: I work at Esri. We added 102719 because at the time, EPSG didn't have the NAD83 feet-based state plane zones. We then 'changed the code' to 2264 to match EPSG a LONG time ago, in 9.0 around 2004.

Comment: I've found that the `standard_parallel_1` and `standard_parallel_2`'s can be swapped without effect